# Issues accessing key value in JSON response from NSURLSession (Lyft API)

Tags: ios, api, swift2, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

I'm working with the new Lyft API, in the Authentication section it says to send a request for an access token and shows an example response, with a key called "access_token".

Sample response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
{
"access_token": <access_token>,
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":3600,
"scope": "public"
}
```

Yet when I make the call (Yes the ClientID and Secret are correct but I can't post them here) it returns a response but the access token is nil.

Thanks for the help like always! Doc link is below,

API docs,

https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication

```
func authorize() {

    let authString = NSString(format: "%@:@%", clientID, clientSecret)
    let authData = authString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let base64String = authData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64String)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let dictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)


        if let accessToken : String = dictionary["access_token"] as? String {

            print(accessToken)
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` instead of `base64EncodedDataWithOptions`?

Comment: The exact the same thing happens... although I did find out from talking to the support staff at Lyft that it's supposed to be a "POST" and not "GET" although even then I'm not getting the right response.

Comment: @Echizzle: I am doing the same integration, do you have any updates on this.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the Lyft docs, I think think the format for your auth string is wrong.

I think you should be doing

`let authString = NSString(format: "%@:@%", clientID, clientSecret)`, not

`let authString = NSString(format: "%@, @%", clientID, clientSecret)`

Comment: Yea someone posted that before but deleted their comment and I updated it, I'm still getting a 400 error though meaning the request was received but there's no auth token.

Comment: You're getting a 400 error? Based off the bottom of the docs page, you're missing a grant_type parameter. It looks like it should be passed as the body of the request. `NSURLRequest` has an `HTTPBody` property of type `NSData`

Comment: I just noticed that, I included it like this, but still not working...        **let bodyDict : [String:AnyObject] = ["grant_type": ["client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token"], "scope": "public"]
        let dataExample : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(bodyDict)
        request.HTTPBody = dataExample**

Comment: Will probably work if you pick one. Make your dictionary `[String:String]` and have it look something like `["grant_type" : "authorization_code", "scope" : "public"]`